# Are there reference implementations of ECQV implicit certificates?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am interested in exploring ECC [implicit certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_certificate), specifically using the [ECQV protocol](http://www.secg.org/?action=secg,docs_draft). While the actual implementation would not difficult to perform using building blocks provided by most ECC capable libraries, I really would like to compare my application with a reference implementation.

Does anyone know of a reference implementation of ECQV?

Comment: ECQV seems to be quite obscure in general, It took quite some time to find the specification.

Comment: @Paūlo: it's worming it's self into numerous specifications in the wireless / smart meter space, along with a host of Certicom patented methods such as ECMQV. It's a perfect match for bandwidth and space constrained systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of moving this question off of the "unanswered" list, the answer seems to be no. I spent time looking as implicit certificates are relevant to a project we are beginning to work on.

SECG, which has the draft standard for ECQV, does have a [future project for test implementations of their standardized primitives/protocols](http://www.secg.org/index.php?action=secg,project_protocol).

They have a mailing list, but I have not subscribed. You could ask there.